# Passing An Argument to a TkInter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a teacher and every week I grade students' participation score. Since I teach computers, I thought I'd create a program to handle that logic for me. I plan on using TkInter to create a start screen with the 4 periods of the day, and depending on the period, it would pull up that class. But I'm trying to use the same class for all 4 periods, since the code is exactly the same.

Here's my code:

```
class part(tk.Tk):
    #Creates a class for the GUI

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Initialization function of partGUI
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="") #default icon in an .ico file
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Lucey's Participation Program") #title

        window = tk.Frame(self)
        window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames= {}



        for F in (StartPage, ClassPart, SettingsPage):
            frame = F(window, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, window):
        #Allows Program to switch windows/pages/frames
        frame = self.frames[window]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
# Home Screen for Program
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        title = tk.Label(self, text="Participation Scores", font=LARGE_FONT)
        title.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        btnPeriod1 = tk.Button(self, text="1st Period", fg="red",
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ClassPart(controller, 1)))
        btnPeriod1.pack()


class ClassPart(tk.Frame):
# Screen showing students, participation buttons & their scores/Hogwarts houses    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, period):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

But this throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/klucey/Documents/partvers2.py", line 307, in <module>
    window = part()
  File "/home/klucey/Documents/partvers2.py", line 40, in __init__
    frame = F(window, self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'period'
```

Any help to a beginner/intermediate would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: when you created the `__init__` function for `ClassPart`, you had a parameter at the end called period, when you later created a `ClassPart` object, you didn't include this parameter, if you include it, it should work

Answer (score 1):

This boilerplate code that you (and everybody else on SO, it seems) are using to handle a multi-page Tkinter app is simply not suitable for handing multiple pages of the same class.  You'd have to put multiple occurrences of `ClassPart` in the page list, and somehow arrange for them to be given a different `period` parameter when constructed - but this breaks the `.show_frame()` method, as you no longer have a unique identifier to select the page to be shown.

Here's what I would suggest instead, given that you have a fixed set of pages (this wouldn't work so well with dynamically-generated pages):

- Get rid of the `period` parameter in your class (so that its constructor is compatible with the other pages).
- Create a subclass of it for each period:

  ```
  class ClassPart1(ClassPart):
      period = 1
  class ClassPart2(ClassPart):
      period = 2
  ```

  ... and so on.  Refer to `self.period` in the base class to access this value.
- Change the initial page creation loop to `for F in (StartPage, ClassPart1, ClassPart2, ClassPart3, ClassPart4, SettingsPage):`.  Use `ClassPart1`, etc. as the identifier to pass to `.show_frame()`.